# How to allow webpage to access clipboard data?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, clipboard, clipboarddata

In my asp.net application when i write something in contentEditable div then following pop-up message display:

**do u want to allow this webpage to access your clipboard?**

**If you allow this, the webpage can access the clipboard data and read information that you've cut or copied recently..**

I don't want it to display every time.

Anybody have any idea how to control it by java-script or jquery?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://canaware.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=413

Comment: Thanks dude,i got exactly what i wanted.